# How to add fragments to activity programatically without XML

Tags: android, xml, fragment, addition

I have an activity without xml layout. Now I'm adding one fragment into activity by:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, profileFragment).commit(); 
}
```

First thing is that I dont know what is R.id.**content**, because i didn't declare it, so where it is from?

Second, how could I add next 2 fragments into activity and place it where I want without xml layout for main activity (first fragment on top, and next 2 fragments side by side below first fragment)?

Comment: is there any reason why you don't want to use a xml layout? Because it is the easiest way.

Comment: Because this is confusing me: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html - "When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the activity first starts"

Comment: Ok, i thought by your question that you didn't want to use xml at all. You could for example make a layout consisting of just empty framelayouts in xml. and then add the fragments to that xml layout in code

Comment: Yes, now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First thing is that I dont know what is R.id.content, because i didn't
>   declare it, so where it is from?

it is not `R.id.content` but `android.R.id.content`, and it is part of the framework

> Second, how could I add next 2 fragments into activity and place it
>   where I want without xml layout for main activity (first fragment on
>   top, and next 2 fragments side by side below first fragment)?

you can create the container(s) for the fragment(s) programmatically (you need to tell Android where do you want the Fragments placed)

Comment: What should be the placeholders for fragments then, FrameLayouts?

Comment: the one that suits better you need. For instance, if you want to have two fragments one next to the other, you could use two FrameLayout inside a horizontal LinearLayout

Comment: Technically speaking you can create all the FrameLayouts and LinearLayouts you need in code and skip using xml files entirely and therefore the "you can't" part isn't really true. But of course there is no reason to do that.